# Resizing ARM Ubuntu Desktop to fit Screen

Tags: 12.10

Well, I am a new member and I have never used Ubuntu before. Yesterday, my mele a1000g single core mini pc arrived in the mail. I tried to use berryboot to install Ubuntu, but it didn't work. So, I dd'd the image of ARM Ubuntu specific for my device to an SD Card. I used the SD Card to transfer that image to the NAND Partition and can now boot Ubuntu without the SD Card. Anyway, it boots quickly, but I cannot see the entire desktop. I can see a sliver of the menu, but none of the text or anything and I have no idea what I am doing. For the most part, all that I can see is the Ubuntu icon in the center of the screen on a black backround. I am used to windows 7. So, I would like some way to resize the desktop slightly smaller so that I can see the entire thing. I have tried changing the display mode on my monitor, but it only resizes the image that it was originally displaying and it doesn't add any more of the edges of the desktop that weren't being displayed. So, that is a useless idea. I would prefer some sort of graphical way of doing this, as I can't do much of anything in the text only environment except typing "startx" and booting Ubuntu. Keep in mind that this is ARM Ubuntu 12.10 running on the mele a1000g single core. I am using the image from this link: http://www.guillaumeplayground.net/mele-a2000-ubuntu-12-10-armhf-nand-xbmc/

Also, Some users of my device have had trouble accessing all of their RAM when booting with this image. For some reason Ubuntu only recognizes 512 mb of the 1 gb RAM that this device has. I would like a quick way to check how much RAM Ubuntu is running on/able to access. Last Question :) Does Ubuntu come with a web browser and how do I find and run it? If not, how would I go about installing one? Thanks so much for all of your help! Keep in mind that I am a complete beginner.

Comment: I am not sure why in the world that formatting is so weird. Do you really have to scroll all the way to the right and left to read it. How can I change that for my next post?

Comment: It's just your browser. The formatting is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to ask only one question per thread.

To know what RAM your hardware has, you can launch :

```
sudo lshw
```

and look at the `*-memory` line. This will tell you haw much RAM your motherboard has, and also exactly how they are placed.

> In my case, for example, it says I have 8 GB installed, and the detail
>   tells me I have 4x 2 GB at 1066Mhz

---

Another way to do this, but that is the RAM your Ubuntu uses, it's to launch :

```
free -h
```

*Mem* table tells you how many RAM your system has, and *-/+ buffers/cache* how much is used currently.

Comment: What do you mean by launch? Where do I type this information?

Comment: You have to type these commandline in a terminal. You can open it with `<Ctrl> + <Alt> + T`or in the launcher search for *Terminal*

Comment: For some reason, ctrl alt t doesn't work for me. And, I can't seee the launcher because the screen is the wrong size.

Comment: Two options then : 1) Press `<Alt>+F2`, type (blindly) `gnome-terminal` and press `<Enter>` 2) Press `<Ctrl> + <Alt> + F1` and log yourself in. Then enter the commandlines. You can re-access your desktop with `<Ctrl> + <Alt> + F7`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I will try that. The main problem that I am having is the screen. I mean, I don't really want to use Ubuntu at all if it won't even work on my screen. It seems silly to have to be typing blindly all the time.

Comment: Well, I can't help you with that. That is precisely why you should only ask one question per thread :)